# how to refer to object and set options after render in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i'm building my first React-Native app

i'm having a table in the render, that i'm inserting like that:

```
render() {
        return (

            <View style={styles.container}>

                {
                    (this.state.loading) ? <Text>Loading</Text>:
                    <CombinedChart
                        data={this.state.data}
                        xAxis={this.state.xAxis}
                        yAxis={this.state.yAxis}
                        legend={this.state.legend}
                        onSelect={this.handleSelect.bind(this)}
                        onChange={(event) => console.log(event.nativeEvent)}
                        marker={this.state.marker}
                        animation={{durationY: 1000,durationX: 1000}}
                        maxVisibleValueCount={16}
                        autoScaleMinMaxEnabled={true}
                        zoom={{scaleX: Math.floor(this.state.days/12), scaleY: 1, xValue:  4, yValue: 4, axisDependency: 'LEFT'}}
                        style={styles.container}/>
                }

                <View style={styles.buttonWrap}>

                    <Button block light onPress={this.zoomTwentyPressed()} style={(this.state.view === 'graph')?styles.buttonStyleCurrent:styles.buttonStyle}>
                        <Text>x100</Text>
                    </Button>
                    <Button block light onPress={this.zoomFiftyPressed()} style={(this.state.view === 'graph')?styles.buttonStyleCurrent:styles.buttonStyle}>
                        <Text>x50</Text>
                    </Button>
                    <Button block light onPress={this.zoomHundredPressed()} style={(this.state.view === 'graph')?styles.buttonStyleCurrent:styles.buttonStyle}>
                        <Text>x25</Text>
                    </Button>

                </View>

            </View>


        );

    }
```

i know from my exp in java, that i can give that object an id, and later call it in the class and use the objects (in this case the 'CombinedChart') options.

How do i call that 'CombinedChart' from another function ??

i'm adding the code with the functions i want to refer the chart in:

```
  zoomTwentyPressed() {
      console.log ("pressed 25");
    }

    zoomFiftyPressed() {
      console.log ("pressed 50");
    }

    zoomHundredPressed() {
      console.log ("pressed 100");
      // CHANGE ZOOM HERE

    }


    static displayName = 'Combined';

    handleSelect(event) {
        let entry = event.nativeEvent
        if (entry == null) {
            this.setState({...this.state, selectedEntry: null})
        } else {
            this.setState({...this.state, selectedEntry: JSON.stringify(entry)})
        }

        // console.log(event.nativeEvent)
    }

    render() {
        return (

            <View style={styles.container}>

                {
                    (this.state.loading) ? <Text>Loading</Text>:
                    <CombinedChart
                        data={this.state.data}
                        xAxis={this.state.xAxis}
                        yAxis={this.state.yAxis}
                        legend={this.state.legend}
                        onSelect={this.handleSelect.bind(this)}
                        onChange={(event) => console.log(event.nativeEvent)}
                        marker={this.state.marker}
                        animation={{durationY: 1000,durationX: 1000}}
                        maxVisibleValueCount={16}
                        autoScaleMinMaxEnabled={true}
                        zoom={{scaleX: Math.floor(this.state.days/12), scaleY: 1, xValue:  4, yValue: 4, axisDependency: 'LEFT'}}
                        style={styles.container}/>
                }

                <View style={styles.buttonWrap}>

                    <Button block light onPress={this.zoomTwentyPressed()} style={(this.state.view === 'graph')?styles.buttonStyleCurrent:styles.buttonStyle}>
                        <Text>x100</Text>
                    </Button>
                    <Button block light onPress={this.zoomFiftyPressed()} style={(this.state.view === 'graph')?styles.buttonStyleCurrent:styles.buttonStyle}>
                        <Text>x50</Text>
                    </Button>
                    <Button block light onPress={this.zoomHundredPressed()} style={(this.state.view === 'graph')?styles.buttonStyleCurrent:styles.buttonStyle}>
                        <Text>x25</Text>
                    </Button>

                </View>

            </View>


        );

    }
}
```

Thnx

Comment: Using `ref` may help you https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-class-component

Comment: Hi, Can you give me an example ?

Answer (score 0):

In your component, set the ref like this:

```
<CombinedChart 
  ref={component => this.combinedChart = component} 
  ... 
/>
```

Then in your other functions, you can access it with `this.combinedChart`.

Comment: hi,vm909 i tried it but then it doesn't let me use the combinedchart properties, such as zoom for example, i'm doing this.combinedChard.zoom = 100, and it just errors it out

Comment: I see what you’re getting at. I would set ‘zoom’ as a state property in your parent component. Make that the value of ‘zoom’ on the chart component. Give your CombinedChart component an ‘onZoomChange’ property (or similar), and use that to set zoom state.